# Error on RenderAction - No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a few areas in project. In one area I have a page (razor) and in it I have added RenderAction() method.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Forum");}
```

Application works but when I run in debug mode my code breaks with error on this line (bellow) I press continue and everything works but I must remove this error.

```
No route in the route table matches the supplied values
```

In Global.asax I add the following route but it doesn't solve the error.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Forum", 
                "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { area = "Forum", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It worked but I don't really understand how???
I added the following code in Global.asax RegisterRoutes() method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Forum", // Route name
                "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Forum", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `area` route parameter:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "forum" });}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. See the end of my question. I actually solve this, but I ma not really sure what I did here.

Comment: Thanks!
This fixed the issue for me. I was using a shared _layout when handling an error redirection.